# Running Unviersal and Classic Analytics together?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to update from Google Classic Analytics to Universal. I have two accounts (One Universal, one Classic) that I want to run on the same website at the same time to compare.

Universal has E-Com Enhanced set up.

Is there any risk in the Classic data being changed or compromised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as they are reporting to separate Properties, there should be no trouble. The only problem would be if you had multiple classic codes.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032400?hl=en